# How do you get an entity id to make calls with the LUIS API?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

There are a number of entity based GET method in the LUIS API which require a GUID for the entity (that is entityId) to be passed in.  Let us take for example delete entity which has the url 
`https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/entities/{entityId}`  .

I can find no way to programmatically get entity ids so that I could make this call.  I know the name of the entity I wish to delete, but not its id.  I cannot get a list of custom entities with their ids that I have defined in my app.

How do I accomplish this?  Solving this problem might make many other calls within my reach as well.

The end goal I am trying to accomplish is to figure out how to delete certain entities, utterances and intents.  There is garbage in my app from experimentation / learning LUIS and I would like to remove these items without recreating a new app.  Using the dashboard is not practical due to rate limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I suppose it is `get_version_entity_list`, with the version being the important part.  Doesn't make sense to me because would you really get the entity list for all versions instead of a specific version?  I was looking more for like get_entity_list.  Oh, well, now I know.

Comment: Can you please explain what you used to get entity ID or intent ID any ID other than APP ID which we can find in website.